# How to view any image format to avif format in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using angular 10. and I want to view / show Image in AVIF format.

With compress version.

**EXAMPLE**: ***Already these kind of images in my database***

(suppose these all image file size is more than 5 mb)

`demoImage.jpeg` or `demoImage.png` or `demoImage.webp`

But when I'm showing in frontend using angular I need to show in AVIF format only

(and this image must be in compressed)

Like this `demoImage.avif`

So how can I archive this?

Comment: why do you want to do this?  do you expect to convert the images in the frontend or backend?

Comment: want to convert from frontend most probably but if its not possible using angular then node is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package [**Sharp**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp), to compress the images to AVIF format. It's also possible to convert it to other formats than that if needed. In it you can also find the most necessary instructions to get it up and running.

Then you can show the image using the  attribute which I guess most browsers support.

```
<picture>
 <source srcSet="image.avif" type="image/avif" />
</picture>
```

Comment: There are a few points why I wouldn't use this solution: Gulp is not remotely compatible with Angular workflows. This library has 100 weekly downloads, wasn't updated since a year and has only one maintainer --> this is kinda dangerous.
Probably OP needs dynamic generation too.

Comment: Yeah, I did some more research about it. Updated the post!